# System of equations and dependent variable standardisation

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, standardization

I am estimating a system of equations with correlated error terms. The model includes three equations. The dependent variables are counts of positive answers on strategies adopted by the household to smooth consumption. The dependent variables have different scales. The first strategy is from 0 to 6, the second from 0 to 5, and the third from 0 to 3.

I am interested in the effect of an independent variable (e.g., household composition) on choosing these strategies and comparing the impact across equations.

My question. Do different metrics in the dependent variables present a problem in such a setup? Would the standardization of the dependent variables address the issue?

Comment: I would use an SEM very cautiously here. A variable in {0,1,2,3} is certainly not normally distributed.

Comment: One needs to compromise somewhere

Comment: Standardizing using sample *SD*s would not make coefficients comparable across DVs.  You could reexpress each DV as the percentage of maximum score (POMS) to get rid of the problem of different scales, assuming the maximum you observed is not also a sample statistic that could differ if you gathered a new sample.